# ROS2 requires colcon build for any changes in python script?

Tags: python, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been using ROS-melodic so far and my python package runs as I changed in the code without any catkin make however I just realized ROS2 is not working like this.
Every time I change the code, it requires colcon build to reveal its modification. Why this is needed?
Is this is intended feature or I am doing it wrong?

FYI, I am using ROS2 foxy on ubuntu 20.04 laptop. Installed ros and workspace as described in the manual.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398200/ros2-requires-colcon-build-for-any-changes-in-python-script?/) by [kyubot](https://answers.ros.org/users/40914/kyubot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2022-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't need to execute colcon build every time you change your python code if you include the option --symlink-install. So use

```
colcon build --symlink-install
```

Best regards

---

Originally posted by [joseecm](https://answers.ros.org/users/44853/joseecm/) with karma: 130 on 2022-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kyubot](https://answers.ros.org/users/40914/kyubot/) on 2022-03-30**:
Great it is working! Thank you so much.